# How do I keep the individual controls on a custom user control from spreading out (and still allow resize)

Tags: winforms, layout

My user control looks like this in its designer.

[[image: My User Control in its designer looks like this:[1]]

But when I drop it into a parent form, it looks like this:

[image: In the parent form it looks like this:]

I have a main panel containing the "Folder" button and the ComboBox.
The little nav buttons on the right are in nested panel.

I'd like for the individual controls to resize, if the font is changed,
but maintain their spacing (It's a pet peeve of mine that so many application cannot handle this well,  e.g. not being able to access the whole form if a large font is used, cutting off labels on buttons, etc).

I've tried a bunch of things, but I'm working with too many variables (anchor, dock, minsize, maxsize, autosize), and not grokking all the interactions.  I'm hoping somebody knows the magic combination, so I don't have to exhaust all the possiblities.

Should I be using a different layout container?  I've not investigated the table or flow layout containers yet.  I assumed they would just complicate things even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use dock or anchor for that (but not both at the same time).

1. Usich anchor you specify to which border of parent the control should have constant distance, so:

   - `Folder` should have anchor set to Top + Bottom + Left
   - `Version` input should have anchor set Top + Bottom + Left + Right
   - Container of the `Up` section should have anchor Top + Bottom + Right;
2. Using dock:

   - `Folder` should have Dock set to Left;
   - `Version` input should have Dock set to Fill and should be the first control added to the container (right click on it in editor end click "Bring to front")
   - Container of the `Up` section should have Dock set to Right

Alternatively you can use `TableLayoutPanel` - first and last column will have constant width, the middle one will stretch with the parent.

Comment: "Bring to Front" does not seem to have the desired effect you describe.  I have to manual change the insertion order in the designer to get the controls to dock in the right.  Both docking and anchoring seem to have undesired side effects.  I tried to include min and max sized, but that sort of defeats the whole purpose.   So the correct answer is use the TableLayoutPanel.